# Creating ViewModels

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, onion-architecture

Maybe some of you have already created working application based on onion architecture, and already dealt with my concerns and are willing share theirs experience.

Here is what bothers me.
Lets assume I have DomainModel "Customer" with 100+ columns.
However for just a particular view I only need `first and last name for rows meeting some specific conditions`

I am using repository/service pattern to expose some basic CRUD stuff.
example service

```
    public class Service<TEntity, TKey> : IService<TEntity, TKey>
        where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>
        where TKey : IComparable
    {
        public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; private set; }
        private readonly IRepository<TEntity, TKey> _repository;
    }

public class CustomerService : Service<Customer,int>, ICustomerService
{
       public ???? GetValidCustomer();
}
```

Now I have 3 ideas how to deal with it but none seems to be good.
*1st) Writing query in controller*

```
var viewModel = _customerRepository().GetAll().Where(...).Select(...).FirstOrDefault();
```

I don't like this solution because it introduces business logic to controller action which also may create repeatable code. If conditions change I will have to look for all queries in entire project in order to change them.

*2nd) Moving View Models to `Service layers`*
Since `Web` is the most outer layer in onion architecture and depends on others inner layers, I am unable to reuse `ViewModel` and write method like this one in `Service layers`, because circular dependencies are not allowed.

```
public ValidCustomerViewModel GetValidCustomer()
{
    return _customerRepository().Where(..).Select(new ValidCustomerViewModel() {....} ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Also creating ViewModel in service layer doesn't seems to be the right place for it, since I assume single service method should have the ability to manipulate domain rather then creating data for view (I think this is `controller` responsibility)

```
public ValidCustomerViewModel GetValidCustomer()
{
    var viewModel = new ValidCustomerViewModel();
        viewModel.Customer _customerRepository().Where(..).Select(new ValidCustomerViewModel() {....} ).FirstOrDefault();
    viewModel.Cats = _catRepository.Where(...).ToList();
} //So bad :(
```

*3rd Creating Dto*
Creating `ont to one` ViewModel and Dto

```
Inside -> (XXX.Web.Portal.ViewModels.Customer)
public class ValidCustomerViewModel()
{
   [Required]
   public string FirstName {get;set;}
   [Required]
   public string LastName {get;set;}
}

Inside ->(XXX.Core.Dto)
public class ValidCustomerDto
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}

public ValidCustomerDto GetValidCustomer()
{
    _customerRepository().Where(..).Project().To<ValidCustomerDto>().FirstOrDefault();
}

var dto = _customerServices().GetValidCustomers();
viewModel = Mapper.Map<ValidCustomerModel>(dto);
```

Well this produces some additional code, but it is open for modification and method returns concrete properties. However this introduces new problem...
Now I may need to write methods like those

```
public List<ValidCustomerDto> GetValidCustomers()
public PaginatedList<ValidCustomerDto>() GetPaginatedValidCustomersList(...)
```

*4rd Returning IQueryable*

```
    public IQuerable<Customer> GetValidCustomer()
     {
        return _customerRepository.Where(...);
     }

 var viewModel = _customerServices.GetValidCustomer().Project.To<MaValidCustomerViewModel>().FirstOrDefault();
```

When I was writing my question, this idea appeared in my head :)
Well this is actually not bad, and I see no major flaws. Waht do you think?

All advices are very welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the 4th idea.

So it will be something like:

Service Layer:

```
public class CustomerService
{
    public ValidCustomerDto GetValidCustomer()
    {
         _customerRepository.GetValidCustomer().Select(x=> new ValidCustomerDto{ FirstName = x.FirstName, LastName = x.LastName });
    }
}
```

As another option, you can create ReadOnly DbContext and use it directly instead of Repositories only for Queries, a separation of Commands and Queries (CQRS idea).